# How to make grid minmax go to 1 column if there is not enough room?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a situation where the size of the container these two columns are in is not consistent with view port width, so I can't easily use breakpoints. I was wondering if there is something within CSS grid that would have a column go from 2 columns to 1 column if there isn't enough width, like what CSS columns does (that's what I am currently using but its having some strange behavior).

```css
  header{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 400px) minmax(200px, 400px);
      grid-gap: 5%;
      
    }
    
    div{
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
    test<br />test
    </div>
    <div>
    test<br />test
    </div>
    <div>
    test<br />test
    </div>
    <div>
    test<br />test
    </div>
    </header>
```

Right now it just overlaps if there isn't enough room, but I want it to wrap if there isn't enough room. I made the sizes 200 and 400 pixels so its easier to test.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/shellwe/msgko8td/5/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution for this by using `display:flex` in your header tag and width screen is not really enough for each div element you can add media query and set some pixels for which each div sections will be wrapped. Here's a css example.

```
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

div{
  background-color: green;
  flex:0 0 45%;
  max-width:45%;
  margin-bottom:0.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  div {
    flex:0 0 100%;
    max-width:100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for taking the time to answer and I started out there but its not quite a solution because of the min size and max size, these cards can be anywhere from 350px to 500px, what I want is if it is 800px then I want it to constrain each one to 400px (assuming some padding)  but then if it goes below 700px for total width then I want it to use the whole 500px width in a single column. That was the trouble I found with flex, is it never cared about min width, it only looked at max width... so it only switched to 2 columns after it was 1000px (max width for both columns) wide

Comment: Also, as mentioned, its not when that screen is 600px, its when that particular container is 600px, which is part of the screen. Depending which screen its on the container may be a side bar or may be the full width. That's why I can't use viewports easily

Comment: I have multiple suggestions for this one.. I'm not quite familiar with `display:grid` so I can't replicate the issue. When you are assigning `div elements` to adjust to any screen I suggest that you should use percent to auto adjust its width depends on the container width. Another suggestion is to use Jquery/Javascript `$(window).width();` function to adjust your `div` element when ever there is a change in your container.